# Java and python ^ operator

Tags: java, python, operators

For a CompSci class, we were reviewing the Java Math class. Being the foolish programmer that I am, I tried using the ^ operator instead of the Math.pow function. Surprise, Surprise, it did not work. But, what Java spit out, is my question. I am trying to figure out the operation that is being done with the numbers. You can see what I am talking about below.

```
System.out.println(5^1);
System.out.println(5^2);
System.out.println(5^3);
System.out.println(5^4);
System.out.println(5^5);
System.out.println(5^6);
System.out.println(5^7);
System.out.println(5^8);
System.out.println(5^9);
```

Running the above, I get the following:

```
4
7
6
1
0
3
2
13
12
```

The same thing happens when I do the equivalent in Python (`print 5^1`, etc...). The Java API doc says that the ^ is a "bitwise exclusive OR", but that still does not help with how have gets 6 from 5 and 3. Could someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Did you consider looking in the Java Language Specification?

Comment: Why **the hell** was this question closed? Are 10 answers not enough to prove that it is actually pretty easy to tell "what is being asked here"?

Comment: Why did you choose to ask here instead of simply googling bitwise exclusive OR?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a *bitwise* operation, and thus it operates on the binary bits of your numbers. 6 is `110` in binary form. 5 is `101` in binary form.

```
110
101
=== (^ xor)
011
```

`011` is 3 in binary.

Read up on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or

Answer (score 3):

Okay so lets take the first example. The easiest one. Take `5^1`.

5 can be represented in binary like so `101` and one can be represented like so `001`.

```
101    XOR
001
---
100 = 4 (in decimal)
```

Because `1 XOR 1 = 0`, `0 XOR 0 = 0` and  `1 XOR 0 = 1`. Just go and check out the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) page on XOR.

Answer (score 2):

This is the [XOR operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or).

```
5 = 101 in binary
3 = 011 in binary

    101
XOR 011 
  = 110 = 6 in decimal
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the `^` operator when applied to `int` arguments is bitwise exclusive-or. That explains the output. For the particular case of 5 and 3:

```
101 (5)
011 (3)
---
110 (6)
```

Note that for logical arguments, it is logical exclusive-or. In that case `(b1 ^ b2) == (b1 != b2)`.

Answer (score 1):

`^` is BitWise XOR operator. So,

```
5 ^ 1: -

101 -> 5
001 -> 1
--- XOR
100 = 4
```

- `1 XOR 1 = 0`
- `1 XOR 0 = 1`

See these links: -

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or

Answer (score 1):

`^` is the [bitwise XOR operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or), and it's truth table looks like this:

```
  | 0 | 1 |
0 | 0 | 1 |
1 | 1 | 0 |
```

So the output bit is `1` only when the inputs are different, and `0` otherwise. So `5 ^ 3` looks like this:

```
  0000 0101 (5)
^ 0000 0011 (3)
= 0000 0110 (6)
```

So it's doing exactly what it's supposed to. Take a look at the [Nuts and Bolts tutorial for bitwise operations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956160/good-tutorials-on-bitwise-operations-in-java) for more references.

Comment: Best answer by far, because of the truth table. +1

Answer (score 1):

It's because of binary representation of five is 101b, of three is 011b.

Xor works in the following way:

```
0 xor 0 = 0
0 xor 1 = 1
1 xor 0 = 1
1 xor 1 = 0
```

Therefore:
101 xor 011 = 110 that is binary representation of six.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this little program helps to explain the exclusive-or operator better using the examples it prints:

```
>>> for x, y in ((x, y) for x in range(11) for y in range(x, 11)):
    print('''{0} ^ {1} = {2} (Why?)
Because:
{0:04b} = {0}
^^^^
{1:04b} = {1}
====
{2:04b} = {2}
'''.format(x, y, x ^ y))


0 ^ 0 = 0 (Why?)
Because:
0000 = 0
^^^^
0000 = 0
====
0000 = 0

0 ^ 1 = 1 (Why?)
Because:
0000 = 0
^^^^
0001 = 1
====
0001 = 1

0 ^ 2 = 2 (Why?)
Because:
0000 = 0
^^^^
0010 = 2
====
0010 = 2

0 ^ 3 = 3 (Why?)
Because:
0000 = 0
^^^^
0011 = 3
====
0011 = 3

0 ^ 4 = 4 (Why?)
Because:
0000 = 0
^^^^
0100 = 4
====
0100 = 4

0 ^ 5 = 5 (Why?)
Because:
0000 = 0
^^^^
0101 = 5
====
0101 = 5

0 ^ 6 = 6 (Why?)
Because:
0000 = 0
^^^^
0110 = 6
====
0110 = 6

0 ^ 7 = 7 (Why?)
Because:
0000 = 0
^^^^
0111 = 7
====
0111 = 7

0 ^ 8 = 8 (Why?)
Because:
0000 = 0
^^^^
1000 = 8
====
1000 = 8

0 ^ 9 = 9 (Why?)
Because:
0000 = 0
^^^^
1001 = 9
====
1001 = 9

0 ^ 10 = 10 (Why?)
Because:
0000 = 0
^^^^
1010 = 10
====
1010 = 10

1 ^ 1 = 0 (Why?)
Because:
0001 = 1
^^^^
0001 = 1
====
0000 = 0

1 ^ 2 = 3 (Why?)
Because:
0001 = 1
^^^^
0010 = 2
====
0011 = 3

1 ^ 3 = 2 (Why?)
Because:
0001 = 1
^^^^
0011 = 3
====
0010 = 2

1 ^ 4 = 5 (Why?)
Because:
0001 = 1
^^^^
0100 = 4
====
0101 = 5

1 ^ 5 = 4 (Why?)
Because:
0001 = 1
^^^^
0101 = 5
====
0100 = 4

1 ^ 6 = 7 (Why?)
Because:
0001 = 1
^^^^
0110 = 6
====
0111 = 7

1 ^ 7 = 6 (Why?)
Because:
0001 = 1
^^^^
0111 = 7
====
0110 = 6

1 ^ 8 = 9 (Why?)
Because:
0001 = 1
^^^^
1000 = 8
====
1001 = 9

1 ^ 9 = 8 (Why?)
Because:
0001 = 1
^^^^
1001 = 9
====
1000 = 8

1 ^ 10 = 11 (Why?)
Because:
0001 = 1
^^^^
1010 = 10
====
1011 = 11

2 ^ 2 = 0 (Why?)
Because:
0010 = 2
^^^^
0010 = 2
====
0000 = 0

2 ^ 3 = 1 (Why?)
Because:
0010 = 2
^^^^
0011 = 3
====
0001 = 1

2 ^ 4 = 6 (Why?)
Because:
0010 = 2
^^^^
0100 = 4
====
0110 = 6

2 ^ 5 = 7 (Why?)
Because:
0010 = 2
^^^^
0101 = 5
====
0111 = 7

2 ^ 6 = 4 (Why?)
Because:
0010 = 2
^^^^
0110 = 6
====
0100 = 4

2 ^ 7 = 5 (Why?)
Because:
0010 = 2
^^^^
0111 = 7
====
0101 = 5

2 ^ 8 = 10 (Why?)
Because:
0010 = 2
^^^^
1000 = 8
====
1010 = 10

2 ^ 9 = 11 (Why?)
Because:
0010 = 2
^^^^
1001 = 9
====
1011 = 11

2 ^ 10 = 8 (Why?)
Because:
0010 = 2
^^^^
1010 = 10
====
1000 = 8

3 ^ 3 = 0 (Why?)
Because:
0011 = 3
^^^^
0011 = 3
====
0000 = 0

3 ^ 4 = 7 (Why?)
Because:
0011 = 3
^^^^
0100 = 4
====
0111 = 7

3 ^ 5 = 6 (Why?)
Because:
0011 = 3
^^^^
0101 = 5
====
0110 = 6

3 ^ 6 = 5 (Why?)
Because:
0011 = 3
^^^^
0110 = 6
====
0101 = 5

3 ^ 7 = 4 (Why?)
Because:
0011 = 3
^^^^
0111 = 7
====
0100 = 4

3 ^ 8 = 11 (Why?)
Because:
0011 = 3
^^^^
1000 = 8
====
1011 = 11

3 ^ 9 = 10 (Why?)
Because:
0011 = 3
^^^^
1001 = 9
====
1010 = 10

3 ^ 10 = 9 (Why?)
Because:
0011 = 3
^^^^
1010 = 10
====
1001 = 9

4 ^ 4 = 0 (Why?)
Because:
0100 = 4
^^^^
0100 = 4
====
0000 = 0

4 ^ 5 = 1 (Why?)
Because:
0100 = 4
^^^^
0101 = 5
====
0001 = 1

4 ^ 6 = 2 (Why?)
Because:
0100 = 4
^^^^
0110 = 6
====
0010 = 2

4 ^ 7 = 3 (Why?)
Because:
0100 = 4
^^^^
0111 = 7
====
0011 = 3

4 ^ 8 = 12 (Why?)
Because:
0100 = 4
^^^^
1000 = 8
====
1100 = 12

4 ^ 9 = 13 (Why?)
Because:
0100 = 4
^^^^
1001 = 9
====
1101 = 13

4 ^ 10 = 14 (Why?)
Because:
0100 = 4
^^^^
1010 = 10
====
1110 = 14

5 ^ 5 = 0 (Why?)
Because:
0101 = 5
^^^^
0101 = 5
====
0000 = 0

5 ^ 6 = 3 (Why?)
Because:
0101 = 5
^^^^
0110 = 6
====
0011 = 3

5 ^ 7 = 2 (Why?)
Because:
0101 = 5
^^^^
0111 = 7
====
0010 = 2

5 ^ 8 = 13 (Why?)
Because:
0101 = 5
^^^^
1000 = 8
====
1101 = 13

5 ^ 9 = 12 (Why?)
Because:
0101 = 5
^^^^
1001 = 9
====
1100 = 12

5 ^ 10 = 15 (Why?)
Because:
0101 = 5
^^^^
1010 = 10
====
1111 = 15

6 ^ 6 = 0 (Why?)
Because:
0110 = 6
^^^^
0110 = 6
====
0000 = 0

6 ^ 7 = 1 (Why?)
Because:
0110 = 6
^^^^
0111 = 7
====
0001 = 1

6 ^ 8 = 14 (Why?)
Because:
0110 = 6
^^^^
1000 = 8
====
1110 = 14

6 ^ 9 = 15 (Why?)
Because:
0110 = 6
^^^^
1001 = 9
====
1111 = 15

6 ^ 10 = 12 (Why?)
Because:
0110 = 6
^^^^
1010 = 10
====
1100 = 12

7 ^ 7 = 0 (Why?)
Because:
0111 = 7
^^^^
0111 = 7
====
0000 = 0

7 ^ 8 = 15 (Why?)
Because:
0111 = 7
^^^^
1000 = 8
====
1111 = 15

7 ^ 9 = 14 (Why?)
Because:
0111 = 7
^^^^
1001 = 9
====
1110 = 14

7 ^ 10 = 13 (Why?)
Because:
0111 = 7
^^^^
1010 = 10
====
1101 = 13

8 ^ 8 = 0 (Why?)
Because:
1000 = 8
^^^^
1000 = 8
====
0000 = 0

8 ^ 9 = 1 (Why?)
Because:
1000 = 8
^^^^
1001 = 9
====
0001 = 1

8 ^ 10 = 2 (Why?)
Because:
1000 = 8
^^^^
1010 = 10
====
0010 = 2

9 ^ 9 = 0 (Why?)
Because:
1001 = 9
^^^^
1001 = 9
====
0000 = 0

9 ^ 10 = 3 (Why?)
Because:
1001 = 9
^^^^
1010 = 10
====
0011 = 3

10 ^ 10 = 0 (Why?)
Because:
1010 = 10
^^^^
1010 = 10
====
0000 = 0

>>>
```

Comment: People are fairly good at recognizing patterns (ie, language). A rule should be rather easily derived from the examples.